# svm classification

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network, svm, pca

I am a beginner in MATLAB and doing my Programming project in Digital Image Processing,i.e. Magnetic Resonance image classification using wavelet features+SVM+PCA+ANN. I executed the example SVM classification from MATLAB tool and modified that to fit my requirements. I am facing problems in storing more than one feature in an input vector and in giving new input to SVM. Please help.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not sure what specific problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply feed multidimensional feature data to [svmtrain(*Training*, *Group*)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/svmtrain.html) function as *Training* parameter (*Training* can be matrix, each column represents separate feature). After that use [svmclassify(*SVMStruct, Sample*)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/svmclassify.html) for testing data classification.

Comment: am not able to classify the new data set by using svmclassify function in matlab and not able to give more than two features as input to classifier,can any bosy help for solving this problem

Comment: @Agnius Please can you help me here? thank you a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449934/multi-class-svm-one-vs-one-always-giving-the-same-label